# Javascript redirects to mobile homepage no matter what link is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have a redirection script that picks up whether the user is on a desktop or mobile device, which works fine but if the user is on a mobile device and clicks on a link for example: www.domain.com/products they get redirected to www.m.domain.com rather than www.m.domain.com/products

Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
<script type ="text/javascript">

  function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    c_name = c_name.toLowerCase();
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
  }

function getCookie(c_name) {
  c_name = c_name.toLowerCase();
  var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
  for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
    x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
    x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    if (x == c_name) {
      //alert("x = " + x); 
      return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function getQuerystring(key, default_) {
  key = key.toLowerCase();
  //alert("key : " + key);
  //alert("default_ : " + default_); 
  if (default_ == null) default_ = "";
  key = key.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + key + "=([^&#]*)");
  var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href.toLowerCase());
  if (qs == null) {
    //alert("default_ : " + default_); 
    return default_;
  } else {
    //alert("qs[1] : " + qs[1]); 
    return qs[1];
  }
}

function detectMobileAndRedirect(a, b) {
  // alert(location.href);

  if (/android|webOS|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|elaine|hiptop|ip(hone|od)|kindle|midp|mmp|mobile|o2|opera mini|palm( os)?|pda|plucker|pocket|psp|smartphone|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce; (iemobile|ppc)|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-)|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) {

    if (/ipad/i.test(a)) {
      return false;
    }
    location.href = b;
  }
}

function removeQueryString(url) {
  return url.split("?")[0];
}
var FullSiteCookie = getCookie("viewFullSite");
var viewFullSite = getQuerystring("viewFullSite");
var renderFullSite = new Boolean();
renderFullSite = false;
if (FullSiteCookie != null && FullSiteCookie != "") {
  if (FullSiteCookie.toLowerCase() == "true") {
    if (viewFullSite.toLowerCase() == "false") {
      setCookie("viewFullSite", false, 1);
    } else {
      renderFullSite = true;
      //alert("Set 11"); 
    }
  } else {
    if (viewFullSite != null && viewFullSite != "") {
      if (viewFullSite.toLowerCase() == "true") {
        renderFullSite = true;
        //alert("Set 2"); 
        setCookie("viewFullSite", true, 1);
      } else {
        if (viewFullSite.toLowerCase() == "false") {
          setCookie("viewFullSite", false, 1);
        }
        renderFullSite = false;
        //alert("Set 3"); 
      }
    } else {
      renderFullSite = false;
      //alert("Set 4"); 
    }
  }
} else {
  viewFullSite = getQuerystring("viewFullSite");
  //alert("viewFullSite 1 : " + viewFullSite); 
  if (viewFullSite != null && viewFullSite != "") {
    if (viewFullSite.toLowerCase() == "true") {
      renderFullSite = true;
      //alert("Set 5"); 
      setCookie("viewFullSite", true, 1);
    } else {
      renderFullSite = false;
      //alert("Set 6"); 
    }
  } else {
    renderFullSite = false;
    //alert("Set 7"); 
  }
}
//alert("renderFullSite : " + renderFullSite); 
if (!renderFullSite) {
  //alert("location href before: " + location.href); 
  var currentLocation = window.location;
  var mobilesite = "https://www.m.domain.com.au";
  var locationhref = removeQueryString(location.href);
  //alert("location href after: " + locationhref); 
  if (locationhref == "https://www.domain.com.au") {
    mobilesite = "http://www.m.domain.com.au/index.php";
  }
  detectMobileAndRedirect(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera, mobilesite);
}

function BookMark() {
  $('#BookmarkImg').animate({
    "top": "-81px"
  }, 1000);
  baseCookieName = "rwbookmark";
  var exdate = new Date();
  var expirehours = "1";
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getHours() + expirehours);
  //use of arbritary stop point so no endless loop occurs 
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    var curName = baseCookieName + i;
    if (document.cookie.indexOf(curName) < 0) {
      document.cookie = curName + "=" + escape(window.location.href) + "[#]contentid=" + document.getElementById("inputContentID").value + "[#]title=" + GetPageTitle() + ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString() + ";path=/;domain=https://www.domain.com.au;";
      break;
    }
  }
  var link = document.getElementById('BookmarkLink');
  link.onclick = null;
  link.style.cursor = "default";
}

function GetPageTitle() {
  var titlefromdom = "";
  var titlefromdomarray = "";
  $(document).ready(function() {
    titlefromdom = document.title;
  });
  titlefromdomarray = titlefromdom.split("|");
  if (titlefromdomarray.length > 0) {
    titlefromdom = titlefromdomarray;
  }
  return titlefromdom;
} 
</script>
```

Comment: thats because you are setting `var mobilesite = "https://www.m.domain.com.au";` and redirect there with `detectMobileAndRedirect(,mobilesite);`, so wherever on the site user has been before, he will always end up on **"www.m.domain.com.au"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code to derive the mobile site URL, you only have

```
var mobilesite ="https://www.m.domain.com.au";
var locationhref = removeQueryString(location.href);
if (locationhref == "https://www.domain.com.au") {
    mobilesite = "http://www.m.domain.com.au/index.php";
}
```

You never appended any path to that URL, so of course it's always going to rediret to `www.m.domain.com.au` and never to `www.m.domain.com.au/products`.

Also, what is that `locationhref` test all about? Looks totally redundant to me.

This may help:

```
var currentPage = window.location.pathname;
var mobilesite = "https://www.m.domain.com.au" + currentPage;
```

If you need to also preserve the query string (the part starting with `?` in the URL), you can find it in `window.location.search`.

Just by the way, device detection is generally not a good idea. If you ever get a chance, make it one responsive / adaptive site and do away with separate mobile sites.

Comment: Thank you so much light you are a champion!